# URL Variable - redirecting to a chosen post

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, redirect

On my website I have a webpage which lists all the post (`home.php`) and one which displays the whole post (`post.php`). I use `postid` as a URL variable and it works fine on the `post.php` (meaning that if I change the URL to `post.php?postid=1`, `post.php?postid=2` and so on the right post appears). However I don't know how to change the code in `home.php` so that it directs to the chosen post (right now it's always directing to `postid=1`, which ever "Read more" I click).
**`home.php`**

```
<?php session_start(); 
php require_once('connection.php');

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_post = "SELECT * FROM post";
$post = mysql_query($query_post, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($post);
$totalRows_post = mysql_num_rows($post);

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_joining = "SELECT * FROM image inner join post on post.postimage = image.imagename";
$joining = mysql_query($query_joining, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_joining = mysql_fetch_assoc($joining);
$totalRows_joining = mysql_num_rows($joining);

...

?>


<ul class="listingposts">
  <?php
  while($row_joining = mysql_fetch_assoc($joining)) {       
  ?>
  <li>
    <a href="post.php?postid=<?php echo $row_post['postid']; ?>">
    <img src="images/<?php echo $row_joining['imagename']; ?>"></a>
    <h3><a href="post.php?postid=<?php echo $row_post['postid']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row_joining['title']; ?>
    </a></h3>
    <p><?php echo $row_joining['description']; ?></p>
    <a href="post.php?postid=<?php echo $row_post['postid']; ?>">Read more</a>
  </li>
  <?php
  }
  ?>   
</ul>
```

**`post.php`**

```
<?php session_start(); 
php require_once('connection.php');

$colname_postviewing = "-1";
if (isset($_GET['postid'])) {
  $colname_postviewing = $_GET['postid'];
}
mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_postviewing = sprintf("SELECT * FROM post WHERE postid = %s", GetSQLValueString($colname_postviewing, "int"));
$postviewing = mysql_query($query_postviewing, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_postviewing = mysql_fetch_assoc($postviewing);
$totalRows_postviewing = mysql_num_rows($postviewing);

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_image = "SELECT * FROM image";
$image = mysql_query($query_image, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_image = mysql_fetch_assoc($image);
$totalRows_image = mysql_num_rows($image);

...

?>

    <div>
     <img class="picture" src="images/<?php echo $row_postviewing['postimage']; ?>">
      <h1><?php echo $row_postviewing['title']; ?></h1>
        <?php if ($totalRows_postviewing == 0) {?>
        <h2>No post.</h2>
        <?php } // Show if recordset empty ?>
        <p><?php echo $row_postviewing['category']; ?></p>
    <p><?php echo $row_postviewing['text']; ?></p>
    </div>
```

**Show tables**

```
post, CREATE TABLE `post` (
  `postid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `text` longtext NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `postimage` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`postid`),
  KEY `fk_post_image1_idx` (`postimage`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_post_image1` FOREIGN KEY (`postimage`) REFERENCES `image` (`imagename`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

image, CREATE TABLE `image` (
  `imagename` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `shortlink` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `source` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imagename`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: can you show post.php

Comment: sure, i'll edit my question in a second :)

Comment: ok. i had posted the answer, perhaps that should help! you can put a logic like that.

Comment: edited my question anyway :) take a look, maybe it will clarify the situation ;)

Comment: ok! and i used mysql_fetch_array for fetching posts. see the only problem was how to loop posts inside another loop.maybe my answer can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need first `SELECT` at all as `INNER JOIN` provides you all the data you need and you iterete on it with `while($row_joining = mysql_fetch_assoc($joining))` so you should use `$row_joining['postid']` to create the URL parametes you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

May be I misunderstood your question, or you simple have a bug in your code: in links href attribute you use $row_post variable, that is not changed in while cycle

If there are sured one-to-one link, you can simple use inner join:

```
<?php session_start(); 
php require_once('connection.php');

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_post = "SELECT post.postid, image.imagename, image.title, post.description FROM image INNER JOIN post ON post.postimage = image.imagename";
$result_post = mysql_query($query_joining, $connection) or die(mysql_error());


?>


<ul class="listingposts">
  <?php
  while($row_post = mysql_fetch_assoc($result_post)) {       
  ?>
  <li>
    <a href="post.php?postid=<?php echo $row_post['postid']; ?>">
    <img src="images/<?php echo $row_post['imagename']; ?>"></a>
    <h3><a href="post.php?postid=<?php echo $row_post['postid']; ?>">
    <?php echo $row_post['title']; ?>
    </a></h3>
    <p><?php echo $row_post['description']; ?></p>
    <a href="post.php?postid=<?php echo $row_post['postid']; ?>">Read more</a>
  </li>
  <?php
  }
  ?>   
</ul>
```

Something like that, I think

Comment: right, i must have overlooked that. I have `$row_joining` looping the images, but not the `postid`. but how do I fix this if I already have one loop? could you help me out with that?

Comment: That depends on what you want. As it looks like from your code, you need to fetch all posts and a set of images for each post, right?

Comment: one post = one image and one title :) images (and some other info about them) is stored in a separate entity in my db, while posts have their own entity. do you need to see `show create table`s?

Answer (score 0):

ok. try this- fetch numeric array for posts.

```
<?php session_start(); 
php require_once('connection.php');

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_post = "SELECT postID FROM post";
$post = mysql_query($query_post, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_post = mysql_fetch_array($post,MYSQL_NUM);
$totalRows_post = mysql_num_rows($post);

mysql_select_db($database_connection, $connection);
$query_joining = "SELECT * FROM image inner join post on post.postimage = image.imagename";
$joining = mysql_query($query_joining, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
$row_joining = mysql_fetch_assoc($joining);
$totalRows_joining = mysql_num_rows($joining);

...

?>


<ul class="listingposts">
  <?php
$i=0;
  while($row_joining = mysql_fetch_assoc($joining)) {       
  ?>
  <li>
    <a href="post.php?postid=<?php echo $row_post[$i]; ?>">
    <img src="images/<?php echo $row_joining['imagename']; ?>"></a>
    <h3><a href="post.php?postid=<?php echo $row_post[$i]; ?>">
    <?php echo $row_joining['title']; ?>
    </a></h3>
    <p><?php echo $row_joining['description']; ?></p>
    <a href="post.php?postid=<?php echo $row_post[$i]; ?>">Read more</a>
  </li>
  <?php
 $i++;
 }
  ?>
```

Comment: i got Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in ...post.php

Comment: `<a href="post.php?postid=<?php echo $row_post[$i]; ?>"><img src="images/<?php echo $row_joining['imagename']; ?>"></a>`

Comment: are you using mysql_fetch_array and also check for values in posts in database